# In SQL, can I get the average of a group of numbers, but only for those records with matching labels?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, average

I have two MySQL tables, one with information about items (called item), and another with customer reviews for those items (called review).

Item contains the label as a text-based primary key, along with some other attributes.
Review contains an auto-incrementing reviewID, along with the item label as a foreign key, and then a review score out of 5.

For example:

```
Item
| LABEL | INFO_1 | INFO_2 | etc|
  book    fict     2010
  book2   nonfic   1997
...

Review
| REVIEWID | LABEL | SCORE |
  001        book     4
  002        book     5
  003        book2    5
```

I want to create a view so that I can see the average review score per item. I have tried to select

```
AVG(review.score) AS avgscore
```

but that returns the same average of every review in the system, without separating it by item label. Do I need to do some kind of join or add further arguments? Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm not exactly super-fluent in MySQL.

My desired result is something like the following:

```
AverageScoreView
| LABEL | AVGSCORE |
  book      4.5
  book2      5
```

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, `AVG()`.

Comment: Show the query you are currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
   SELECT LABEL, AVG(SCORE) AS AVGSCORE
    FROM Review
    GROUP BY LABEL
```